# How to disable mouse over highlight effect on user control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have searched for same question scenarios but they are unclear and most focus on buttons and not user controls.

I have a user control that I load from a mainwindow this way:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{           
    ContentArea.Content = new Views.DashboardView();
}
```

but when that usercontrol is loaded, when i hover over it with my mouse, the entire window is highlighted instead of highlighting individual controls within that window

[image: user control highlighted]

the control surrounded by a black outline is the usercontrol highlighted wholly on mouse over event. Is there a way to disable this highlighting effect and just highlight for example the "Manage" button within the usercontrol without also highlighting the entire control.

Here is my usercontrol XAML code:

```
<UserControl x:Class="S.O.B_Management_System.Views.DashboardView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:S.O.B_Management_System.Views"
    mc:Ignorable="d"            
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="540">

    <Grid>
        <ListView>
            <ScrollViewer Height="300">
                <StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Background="LightBlue" Width="150" Height="90" Margin="10">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <TextBlock Margin="10" Width="130" Background="White" Text="TRIANGLES" Padding="35,3,5,3" FontFamily="Century Gothic"/>
                        <Button Content="Manage" Width="100" Margin="0,15,0,0" Click="Button_Click"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                    </TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Background="LightBlue" Width="150" Height="90" Margin="10">
                        </TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Background="LightBlue" Width="150" Height="90" Margin="10">
                        </TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

and my mainwindow XAML code:

```
<Window x:Class="S.O.B_Management_System.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:S.O.B_Management_System"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:S.O.B_Management_System.Views"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="700" Width="1250">
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:DashboardView}">
            <vm:DashboardView />
            <!-- This is a UserControl -->
        </DataTemplate>

    </Window.Resources>
    <DockPanel>
        <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <MenuItem Header="Test">
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <DockPanel>
                
                <StackPanel Width="230"  Orientation="Vertical" DockPanel.Dock="Left">
                    <ListView Height="400">
                        <ListViewItem Name="dash" Content="Dashboard" FontFamily="Century Gothic" FontWeight="Bold" Height="30" Background="AliceBlue">
                           
                        </ListViewItem>
                        <ListViewItem Content="Inventory" FontFamily="Century Gothic" FontWeight="Bold" Height="30" Background="AliceBlue"/>
                        <ListViewItem Content="Dashboard" FontFamily="Century Gothic" FontWeight="Bold" Height="30" Background="AliceBlue"/>
                        <ListViewItem Content="Dashboard" FontFamily="Century Gothic" FontWeight="Bold" Height="30" Background="AliceBlue"/>
                        <ListViewItem Content="Dashboard" FontFamily="Century Gothic" FontWeight="Bold" Height="30" Background="AliceBlue"/>
                        <Button Height="20" Width="60" Content="{Binding Name}"
                          Command="{Binding DataContext.ChangePageCommand,
                             RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
                          CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                          Margin="2,5" Click="Button_Click"/>
                    </ListView>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" DockPanel.Dock="Right">

                    <ContentControl x:Name="ContentArea" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DockPanel>    
        </StackPanel>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: I'm not sure but I think some of your either stackpanels or dockpanels can be the theif in this. If you feel like this is a hazzle just create a trigger with a style for everytime our mouse enter the usercontroll area.

Comment: I'd not recommend nesting stackpanels inside textblocks, but thats a different story... There is definitely something going on in code that you didn't show in this question. The mouse over effect is not defined in the shown XAML.

Comment: Bojje your solution is the answer , unfortunately because im under 15 in reputation i cant upvote your comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the issue by removing intertwined stack panels in my DashboardView

```
<UserControl x:Class="S.O.B_Management_System.Views.DashboardView"
   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
   xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
   xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
   xmlns:local="clr-namespace:S.O.B_Management_System.Views"
   mc:Ignorable="d"            
   d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="540">

    <Grid>
        <DockPanel>       
            <ListView Height="400" DockPanel.Dock = Top>
                <ListViewItem Name="dash" Content="Dashboard" FontFamily="Century Gothic" FontWeight="Bold" Height="30" Background="AliceBlue" />
                <ListViewItem Content="Inventory" FontFamily="Century Gothic" FontWeight="Bold" Height="30" Background="AliceBlue"/>
                <ListViewItem Content="Dashboard" FontFamily="Century Gothic" FontWeight="Bold" Height="30" Background="AliceBlue"/>
                <ListViewItem Content="Dashboard" FontFamily="Century Gothic" FontWeight="Bold" Height="30" Background="AliceBlue"/>
                <ListViewItem Content="Dashboard" FontFamily="Century Gothic" FontWeight="Bold" Height="30" Background="AliceBlue"/>
                <Button Height="20" Width="60" Content="{Binding Name}"
                    Command="{Binding DataContext.ChangePageCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" 
                    CommandParameter="{Binding}" Margin="2,5" Button_Click"/>
            </ListView>
        </DockPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a style trigger that includes IsMouseOver for the part you're interested in. For example, to change the colour of the selected listbox item when the mouse is over it you could do this

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

If you're not using resource dictionaries it may be easier to define the style in the user control itself. For example, if you've got a listbox nested within a popup and you want to change the colour of the selected item you could do this

```
<UserControl>
    <Grid>
        <TextBox>
        <Popup>
            <ListBox>
                <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            </ListBox>
        </Popup>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: That would probably be a solution for the question, how to *enable* a style on mouseover. However, the question is how to *disable* some mouseover effect. So I doubt there is an answer until we see how the effect is currently implemented.

Comment: I had a similar problem about 6 months ago; I had a listbox in a popup and wanted to highlight the selecteditem on mouse over. I found that placing the IsMouseOver trigger on the listboxitem rather than on the usercontrol worked. 

In this case, to highlight the manage button on mouse over you should place the IsMouseOver trigger on the button and not the usercontrol.

Comment: Your solution would work however in this case the issue was somewhere in my stack panels. I removed the stack panels and docked my listview and the problem is gone. Using your solution with the stack panels intertwined as they were would still lead into issues. Thank you